# How to render expressions in matlab gui?

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, expression

I want to convert mathematical expressions from a string in LaTeX format to their neat form.
My initial solution was using another program to convert string to image and loading the image in gui.
Is there such program or Matlab function (that gets a latex string as input and creates an image that can be loaded in Matlab)? or is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command and it's `'Interpreter'` property - it can be set to `'Latex'` and provide you with the functionality you want. (see last example in the doc).

Comment: But normal GUI elements (button, edit, static text) do not render LaTeX strings (at least until R2011b), while axes title, labels, and text elemets do. @Ehsan, you may create transparent axes in your GUI and display your LaTeX string there, as Shai suggested.

Comment: thanx! it worked! I used text('some parameters...', 'Interpreter', 'Latex');